# Button's onclick records the i tag instead of the button itself

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a button and I want to capture its 'id' when it is clicked.

```
<button id={props.id} 
   onClick={props.handleClick} 
   className="btn btn-circle" >
   <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
</button >
```

When I log the event `console.log(event.target.id);` in my handleClick function, it returns the i tag's 'id' (which is just an empty string) if I click in the middle of the button. If I click on the sides of the button, then my handleClick function works as intended.

This is what the button looks like for reference
[image]

How should I fix this? I suppose I can add the same 'id' attribute to the i tag, but was wondering if there was a better fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You could use [currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) instead:**

```
console.log(event.currentTarget.id);
```

This will return the `currentTarget` that you have attached your `onClick` function on, not the `target` that triggers the event.

Answer (score 0):

you also can use this way to get id value

```js
import { render } from "react-dom";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class Click extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  click(e) {
    let id = e.target.attributes.getNamedItem("id").value;
    alert(id);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.click} id="This is id">
        Click Here
      </button>
    );
  }
}
export default Click;
```